# What is the proper at-command for stk to enter data

Tags: at-command, sim-toolkit

I have successfully entered into the stk then went through the menu and sub-menu but in one place I got stuck. It asks to enter a phone number but when I do that and press enter it keeps on prompting. Below is the full at commands I used and their responses:

```
AT+STGI=0

+STGI: "ERS"
+STGI: 128,1,"Prepaid TopUp",0,33

OK
AT+STGR=0,1,128

OK

+STIN: 6
AT+STGI=6

+STGI: 0,"Prepaid TopUp"
+STGI: 1,6,"Recharge",0
+STGI: 2,6,"Postpaid",0
+STGI: 3,6,"Last Recharge",0
+STGI: 4,6,"Stock Balance",0
+STGI: 5,6,"Daily Report",0
+STGI: 6,6,"Change PIN",0

OK
AT+STGR=6,1,1

OK

+STIN: 3
AT+STGI=3

+STGI: 0,1,6,13,0,"Customer Mobile No"

OK

AT+STGR=3,1,1

>292391929
>
```

When I type in AT+STGR=3,1,1 and press enter it prompts me to enter the number but when I type the number and press enter it keeps on prompting no matter how many times I press enter. So I have tried doing the same thing with putty and same thing happened. So what exactly am I missing? I am writing a program in vb.net, is there anything which I have to enter with the string which sends the phone number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok found the solution, just need to press ctrl+z